# Android: Client-Server using TCP, and discovery of PC/Mac on LAN (WiFi)

Tags: android, sockets, networking, arp

I want to create app in client-server model. So I written desktop server and mobile client library. Now I encounter some problem with automatically discover PC/Mac computer in LAN network from Android device.

Possible solutions:

1. get android device ip address, get subnet mask, use `org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils` class to `getInfo().getAllAddresses()` and scan them all using `InetAddress.isReachable(timout=1000ms)` This solution works but if we have optimistic subnet mask 255.255.255.0 it must scan 254 addresses and it takes 254 seconds => > 4min. Ok I could use threads, maybe addition of 10 threads and splitting this task to check about 26 ip addresses could make it below <45 seconds. But there also can be subnet mask 255.255.0.0 (less probable but...).
2. Android don't have `arp -a` command line tool, but it has something like `/proc/net/arp` file? I am reading this file and can get some ip addresses in LAN very fast, I can reject IP addresses that don't have real MAC but `00:00:00:00:00:00`. I could also find then vendor of this device also using some api, local database? 
   The problem is that I have read this file has some drawbacks like contains non existent devices (after their disconnection)? and not all devices actually connected? Is it right? So Can I relay on it or not?

Both above solutions enable to find only IP address, what about port number of my server app. Ok I could use fixed port number (but it can be used by some other service and then there will be problem). Maybe trying consecutive addresses from xxxx port number like, xxxx+1, xxxx+2,.... etc. to the moment I find some on which I can correct. So the connection could take reasonable amount of time I suppose.

3. I have read about NSD or DNS-SD: 
   https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html
   This seems to enable register some service (In my case my server-side app) and enable it to be discovered in local network by other devices? Is this useable in the case of PC/MacOS server app registering for discovery, and Android App finding this service using NSD?

When I have IP address how can I get name of the device: 
i.e. name that is displayed here "Play Internet 4G..." which is my wifi router.

[image]

or the name of my computer that is displayed here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think using `NSD` (Network Service Discovery) implementing `DNS-SD` (Service Discovery) and on MacOS (also Windows, iOS) **`Bonjour`**

```
http://developer.apple.com/bonjour
```

Will be the best way to implement discovery of devices (services offered by client-server local network software) in LAN. You can get also descriptive names like name of the computer or server app running on that computer to show the end user. There is dns-sd  command line tool in Terminal on macOS you  can test registration of services in network and their later discovery. It works perfectly well and fast. Example screenshot of my Android app discovering service registered in macOS command line tool.

[image]

Watch more: 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/211/